# How to mock axios zip download call, using axios-mock-adaptor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I have a code which is downloading the zip as `arraybuffer` and subsequently uses admZip to get the files inside. I am trying to unit test a method which calls this method and got stuck around `mocking` the zip download call.

The code is -

```
export const downloadZip = async (zipUrl: string): Promise<Buffer>  => {
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({ headers: getHeaders() });
  const body = await axiosInstance.get(zipUrl, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  });
  
  return body.data
}
```

Does anyone have any prior experience on this and can help?

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

```js
const mock = new MockAdapter(axiosInstance);
mock.onGet("https://zip_url").reply(200, {data: "zipData"});

await expect(AxiosClient().get("https://zip_url")).tobe({data: "zipData"})
```